# Unable to run my app again after opening my database with the Server Explorer

Tags: entity-framework

I successfully use EF4 to build my database from scratch. My database is an SQL EXPRESS database file. I can manage this one with Sql Server Management Studio. So far so good.

[image]

**I noticed that if I open my database with the Server Explorer in Visual Studio, the next time I run the application I got errors.**

[image]

[image]

*I also noticed that a new log file has been created. So now I have 2 log files.*

[image]

Below is my connectionstring:

```
<add name="DocumentManagerEntities" 
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS2008;Initial Catalog=DocumentManagerDB;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|DocumentManagerDB.mdf;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

What's wrong?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That maybe because multiple applications are trying to use your database at once. You need to close one connection to open another.

This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247257%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) notes that

> SQL Server Express Edition allows only a single connection to an .mdf
>   file when you connect with a connection string that has User Instance
>   set to true.

Further more

> When you connect to a local database project, Visual Web Developer
>   connects to the SQL Server Express Edition database with user
>   instances enabled, by default. For example, the following code example
>   shows a typical connection string used by Visual Web Developer to
>   connect to a SQL Server Express Edition database.

Comment: I understand and agree with the idea. But in my case, here are the steps: I run my app, the database is automatically created, I close my app, in VS I connect to my databse with Server Explorer, next I close the connection, next I try to run my app again BUT I got error. So, everytime I use the Server Explorer I cannot run my app anymore... What's wrong?

Comment: @Bronzato you need to right click the connection in Server Explorer and select `Close Connection`